# C - Read special characters like 'ã' using scanf

Tags: c

Is it possible to make `scanf` read all special characters?

I know that you can use `scanf("%[^\n]s", string)` to "force" scanf to accept whitespaces, but can I do the same with special characters?

When I try inputing "Não", for instance, the result is just "N". It's like the `scanf` stops reading from input after encountering an unicode character.

I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: You'll probably need to use `wchar` and the related functions to read and store it, as Unicode characters don't fit in `sizeof(char)`, and strings are merely made up of `chars`.

Comment: What happens when you try? - @anonmess: it is not necessary if OP is relying on Latin-1 encoding, the default for Windows. That character is a one-byte value in there.

Comment: @usr2564301 When I try inputing "Não", I only get "N". It's like the scanf stops reading when it gets to the unicode character.

Comment: Hmm. It sounds like you should [edit] your post and add details such as your exact OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf` only reads chars. You need to use `wchar` to store multi-byte characters. You can use [wscanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/wscanf) to read multi-byte characters.